# How do I load a scene from another scene while activating one gameobject and deactivating the other?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to open a non-main menu bar located in another scene.

```
SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(Name);
```

It's work but open main menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to open the menu bar in another scene, there is a workaround: create this submenu in the current scene, and when you close it, go to the main menu of the other scene